# bind specific elements of a list

Tags: r, list

I have a list containing elements of different lengths.
I would like to bind together elements having length of less than `L`, and replace the individual short elements with the united element.

For example:

```
L = list()
for (i in 1:3) {
    L[[i]] = seq(1:i)
}
```

I would like to unite elements 1,2 into element "12" containing the numbers 1,1,2 instead of the first two elements.
How can I do this systematically (in a loop, or vectorially)?

The desired result is: first element c(1,1,2), second element c(1,2,3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may do

```
c(list(unlist(L[lengths(L) < 3])), L[lengths(L) >= 3])
# [[1]]
# [1] 1 1 2
#
# [[2]]
# [1] 1 2 3
```

The second part, `L[lengths(L) >= 3]`, contains all the long enough elements of `L`. Then `L[lengths(L) < 3]` is the list of all the short elements of `L`, and `unlist` combines them together.

Answer (score 1):

We get the `max` `length` of the `list` ('L'), get a logical index by comparing with the `lengths`, concatenate those elements are not matching the max length and append with the other list element

```
i1 <- max(lengths(L))
i2 <- i1 != lengths(L)
c(list(Reduce(`c`, L[i2])), L[!i2])
#[[1]]
#[1] 1 1 2

#[[2]]
#[1] 1 2 3
```